# ReplaceReturnType for generic object

Tags: typescript

```
type ReplaceReturnType<T extends (...a: any) => any, TNewReturn> = (
  ...a: Parameters<T>
) => TNewReturn

type TService<Obj> = {
  [Prop in keyof Obj as Prop]: ReplaceReturnType<Obj[Prop], Iterator>
}
```

i try change return type of Obj[Prop] that is function but have error

> Type 'Obj[Prop]' does not satisfy the constraint '(...a: any)
> => any'.   Type 'Obj[keyof Obj]' is not assignable to type '(...a: any) => any'.     Type 'Obj[string] | Obj[number] | Obj[symbol]' is
> not assignable to type '(...a: any) => any'.       Type 'Obj[string]'
> is not assignable to type '(...a: any) => any'.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a constraint to `Obj` so that typescript knows all properties of this type are functions:

```
type ReplaceReturnType<T extends (...a: any) => any, TNewReturn> = (
  ...a: Parameters<T>
) => TNewReturn

type TService<Obj extends Record<PropertyKey,  (...a: any) => any>> = {
  [Prop in keyof Obj as Prop]: ReplaceReturnType<Obj[Prop], Iterator<any>>
}
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAShYBsCGBjCdgFcBOA7AKuBADz5QQAewEuAJgM5QAUAdG0gFxRK4gCUUALwA+brwA0UfADkIAdww5cowcwBQUKGxacoABSTYkAWwjVs9UsLUCRU2QrNK1a0JCkBlCNgBuASzRiAHkAIwArcioaBlgIFAB7bFpiPWx4yGxQAGkIEElmbV0efiFRYuEVKABvDSgAbVT0qD9cKABrXPiAMyhQiKRGRrAAXS44RFR0JzxCSGDwhrSRyQBJcyRgROJy6wBfIA)

Comment: but then i lost what is my arguments in function

my first solution was this and it lost args in same way 
`
type TService<Obj> = {
  [Prop in keyof Obj as Prop]: (...a: any) => Iterator
}
`